# representing tensor-C*-categories in BIM

Tags: subfactors, von-neumann-algebras, monoidal-categories

Given a factor *M* (=von Neumann alg. with center ℂ), let us write *BIM* for the ⊗-*C**-category of *M*-*M*-bimodules.

> Which ⊗-*C**-categories can one faithfully embed into *BIM*?

⓵  Are there ***necessary*** conditions for a ⊗-*C**-category to be representable in *BIM*?
⓶  Are there ***sufficient*** conditions for a ⊗-*C**-category to be representable in *BIM*?

*Comment:*
I suspect that a lot is known about ⓶ in relation with the theory of planar algebras...
I specially care about ⓵: are there examples of ⊗-*C**-categories that don't embed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about necessary conditions, but here are some results concerning sufficient conditions:

- In MR1749868, Hayashi and Yamagami realize amenable $C^*$-tensor categories in the category of bifinite (Jones index) bimodules of the hyperfinite $II_1$-factor.-
- In arXiv:0811.1764v4, Stefaan Vaes and Sébastien Falguières showed that "the representation category of any compact group is the [bifinite] bimodule category of a $II_1$-factor," i.e., given a compact group $G$ with representation category $C$, there is a $II_1$-factor $M$ whose category of bifinite bimodules is exactly $C$.-
- Recently, Sven Raum and Sébastien Falguières showed that "all finite $C^*$-tensor categories are [bifinite] bimodule categories of a $II_1$-factor," i.e., given a finite $C^*$-tensor category $C$, there is a $II_1$-factor $M$ whose category of bifinite bimodules is exactly $C$. This paper has yet to appear on the arXiv. Here is the [link](http://genco-2011.institut.math.jussieu.fr/program.html) to the conference at which the talk was given.-

I don't know of such results for type $III$ factors.

Comment: This is only an answer to half of my question. But it is very informative, so I'll accept it.